# Advertising Package for BLE in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am creating windows phone 8.1 "Bluetooth Low Energy Application", how do I discover nearby BLE devices' "Name and MAC address" using code without pairing? In Android, there is a support with the use of advertising package. Is this possible in Windows Phone 8.1 or not? I have to return MAC address to web service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has not yet been implemented.
Microsoft is "listening" to developers and are looking into This as well as Peripheral mode and more.
Very unfortunate for WP8.1 that is doesn't want to use the growing number of amazing BTLE devices.